# Lazy<T> implementation and .NET generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, lazy-loading

I was looking for ways to do lazy initialization and found [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) which is included in .NET 4.

I was thinking of rolling my own implementation of `Lazy<T>` for .NET 3.5 (with a simpler multi-thread policy), and I bumped into the following problem:

Lazy has basically two types of constructors:

```
class Lazy<T> {

    public Lazy(){...} // ctor #1
```

which uses T's default constructor for creating an instance of T, and

```
    public Lazy(Func<T> func){...} // ctor #2
```

which lets the caller decide how the instance of T is created.

Now here's the problem:

If I want compile-time checking for the 1st ctor I will add a restriction

```
class Lazy<T> where T: new() {...}
```

at the class level. This will allow me to use `new T()` to create an instance; but this restriction is not necessary for the 2nd ctor, and worse, it also restricts the types I can use (to those with a default ctor)

If I want to be able to use any type with the 2nd ctor, I will not set any restriction, and in the 1st ctor will use reflection to make sure `T` does have a default ctor. This approach, however, will lack the compile-time check, and will only throw a runtime  exception if the 1st ctor is used with the wrong type.

My question is: Can I get the best of both worlds?

Ideally, I would like to get the compile-time check for every use of ctor #1, but at the same time be able to use ctor #2 for types that don't have a default ctor.

How does the Microsoft implementation do this? (I don't readily have access to the .NET 4 sources or dlls).

EDIT: (After "Reflector-ing" the MS assembly)

I checked the reference implementation and it doesn't do compile-time checks.
It uses reflection for the 'default ctor' case, of course accompanied by the runtime exception if things go bad.

Comment: You can use Reflector to look at the .NET 4 implementation

Comment: @Thomas I like quoting myself. Makes me sound important: "I don't readily have access to the .NET 4 sources or dlls"... or at least that was true when I asked the question. In the mean time, thanks to Lucas' hint, I got a hold of the assemblies and updated the question with my findings.

Comment: OK, I missed the "or dlls" part... sorry

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I expect the inbuilt implementation simply uses `Activator.CreateInstance<T>` for simplicity. The cleanest way I can think of cheating this is with a separate factory:

```
// non-generic factory class with generic methods
public static class Lazy {
    public static Lazy<T> Create<T>() where T : new() {
        return Create<T>(() => new T());
    }
    public static Lazy<T> Create<T>(Func<T> ctor) { ... }
}
public class Lazy<T> { ... }
```

Comment: One person's cheat is another's design pattern. :)

Answer (score 7):

**You could use a static factory method instead of a overload to the constructor:**

```
public class Lazy<T>
{
    public Lazy( Func<T> f ) { /*...*/ }

   public static Lazy<R> Default<R>() where R : T, new()
   {
       return new Lazy<R>( () => new R() );
   }
}
```

Now, this breaks compatibility (to some extent) with the .NET 4.0 version of `Lazy<T>`, but it does achieve compile time safety for both types of usage.

You could make this a bit cleaner by making the constructors for `Lazy<T>` protected internal, and provide a static factory class that you always use to create instances:

```
public static class Lazy {
    static Lazy<T> Create<T>( Func<T> ) { ... }
    static Lazy<T> Create<T>( ) where T : new() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Erm... excuse my ignorance, but how can I call a protected ctor of Lazy<T> from Lazy ?

Comment: I meant to write `internal protected` - I'll amend that.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just download the parallel extesions and install `Lazy<T>` for 3.5? [Direct link](http://services.social.microsoft.com/feeds/FeedItem?feedId=08062598-5b53-4d07-bebd-dca1b7dd1312&itemId=3af69bcb-1b45-4ab9-960b-172129eb4134&title=Parallel+Extensions+for+.NET+3.5+SP1+on+DevLabs&uri=http%3a%2f%2fgo.microsoft.com%2ffwlink%2f%3fLinkId%3d182996&k=3ETW9pqVZteBO3qm%2b3lBaJa8gvE%2fRvDfaTCG%2fWKQsic%3d)

Comment: Because it's a pain to get the company's approval for using any 3rd party libraries. :(

Comment: Ooh... but now I can pry my nose in the vanilla implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: Can I get the best of
>   both worlds?

No.

Basically you have no compile time checkable constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you. We used this in our local code base for a year or so before moving to 4.0.

```
public class Lazy<T> {
  private Func<T> func;
  private T result;
  private bool hasValue;
  public Lazy(Func<T> func) {
    this.func = func;
    this.hasValue = false;
  }
  public T Value {
    get {
      if (!this.hasValue) {
        this.result = this.func();
        this.hasValue = true;
      }
      return this.result;
    }
  }
}
```